# Query list of RealmDates inside RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I have a `RealmObject` `Event`, containing a `RealmList` of `RealmDate`s on which this specific object is valid. I would like to query on Events that are valid on a specific date, and ONLY that date. The first part can be queried by:

`realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("validDates.date", date)`

I would expect I could query for the second part with the following query:

`.equalTo("validDates.size", 1)`

However, this throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. Is it possible to query for the size of a list in Realm, and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not yet. There is an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1598